# Модифицировать метод скрытия клавиатуры

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть метод который скрывает клавиатуру

```
private fun hideKeyboard() {
    val imm = activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm?.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS)
}
```

Работает норм, но `toggleSoftInput()` всегда срабатывает при нажатии по элементу. То скрывает, то показывает клавиатуру, а мне надо чтобы только скрывало. Как можно модифицировать метод? Так понимаю как то с помощью `iBinder'a`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте данный метод:

```
private fun hideKeyboard(View view) {
    val imm = activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm?.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS, null)
}
```

Метод `hideSoftInputFromWindow()` может принимать на вход 3 параметра

- `IBinder windowToken` - Маркер окна, из которого делается запрос. Возвращается методом `view.getWindowToken()`. [подробнее об IBinder...](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/IBinder.html)
- `int flags` - Дополнительные рабочие флаги. [подробнее о флагах (раздел Constants)...](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html)
- `ResultReceiver resultReceiver` - Подобие [`BroadcastReceiver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). Если не равно `null`, то он будет вызываться по IME, когда он обработает ваш запрос, чтобы сказать вам, что он обработан. `resultCode`, который вы получите может быть равен одному из этих значений [`RESULT_UNCHANGED_SHOWN`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#RESULT_UNCHANGED_SHOWN), [`RESULT_UNCHANGED_HIDDEN`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#RESULT_UNCHANGED_HIDDEN), [`RESULT_SHOWN`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#RESULT_SHOWN) или [`RESULT_HIDDEN`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#RESULT_HIDDEN). [подробнее o ResultReceiver...](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html)

*Вольный перевод сайта https://developer.android.com/*

Comment: там три параметра '(IBinder windowToken, 
                int flags, 
                ResultReceiver resultReceiver)'

Comment: @Morozov  в java реализации этот метод может иметь 2 параметра, а именно: `(IBinder windowToken, int flags)`, так как брал пример с java то получилась такая неточность. Спасибо за замечание, исправил ответ.

Comment: @zTrap 0 подчеркивает  - the integer literal doesn t conform to the expected IBinder!

Comment: @Inkognito попробуйте передать в метод `View`, на который было произведено нажатие. А в методе заместо 0 подставить `view.getWindowToken()`

Comment: @zTrap да я так и сделал, просто компилиться долго) а зачем getWindowToken тут нужен и как он влияет на view?

Comment: @Inkognito https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#hideSoftInputFromWindow(android.os.IBinder, int, android.os.ResultReceiver) на ознакомление

Comment: @Inkognito дополнил ответ